# SQL Server throws an error "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint" even when using NOCHECK CONSTRAINT

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am using a small application and every SQL query that writes or read from the database works fine except the delete. I can't understand what I am doing wrong since I deactivated all constraints.

I am using this query but I keep getting the error (only the `DELETE FROM [dbo].[Orders]` is causing this error, the history deletion works fine)

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Order_Details".

Here is the SQL query :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all;

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Orders] 
WHERE ([OrderID] = @OrderID);

DELETE FROM [dbo].[History] 
WHERE ([OrderID] = @OrderID);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] CHECK CONSTRAINT all;
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraint `FK_Order_Details` is on *another* table.  Probably one called "OrderDetails".

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and it helped me solve the problem. Subquestion :When you temporarly deactivate constrains on the table that you want to modify even if they are FK's you should not be able to make the changes without affecting all the other tables?

Comment: That change would have created orphaned rows on the other table, which its FK is there to prevent.